# Line 16: React Hook "useState" is called conditionally

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofIfc.png)

```
const Credits = ({ cast, baseUrl }) => {
  if (!cast) {
    return;
  }
  const [totalShow, setTotalShow] = useState(null);
  const sliderElement = useRef();

  // Set amount of items to show on slider based on the width of the element
  const changeTotalShow = () => {
    let totalItems = Math.round(sliderElement.current.offsetWidth / 70);
    if (totalItems > cast.length) {
      totalItems = cast.length;
    }
    setTotalShow(totalItems);
  };

  const items = cast.map(person => ());

  useEffect(() => {
    changeTotalShow();
    window.addEventListener("resize", changeTotalShow);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", changeTotalShow);
  }, []);

  const settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: totalShow,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    nextArrow: ,
    prevArrow: ,
  };

  return { items };
};
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

First you should look at the [rule of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), so you know what you can and can't do with hooks. You will notice that you can't have hooks called conditionally which means with every render you should have the same number of hooks. You dont as it can be that if `!credits` the render will not call anything. I presume if you will move

```
  if (!cast) {
    return;
  }
```

below any hooks the warning/error will go away.